# Canvas does not paint colors

Tags: oop, canvas

i am learning Canvas, but it does not paint colors:
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Canvas</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.css">
</head>
<body>

    <Canvas id="c1" height="200px" width ="400px">ooo</Canvas>
    <script src="JS/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#c1{
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
    background-image: url(../images/setka.png);
}
```

JS

```
function Figure(x,y, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.сolor = color;
};
function Line(x1, y1, x2, y2, color) {
    Figure.call(this, x1, y1, color);
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.y2 = y2;
    this.draw = function(ctx) {
        // let ctx = document.getElementById('c1').getContext('2d');
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
        ctx.lineTo(this.x2,this.y2);
        ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
        ctx.stroke();
    }
};

function Rect(x,y,width, height, color) {
    Figure.call(this, x, y, color);
    this.w = width;
    this.h = height;
    this.draw = function(ctx) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x,this.y, this.w, this.h);
    }
};
function Circle(x,y, r, color) {
    Figure.call(this, x, y, color);
    this.rad = r;
    this.draw = function(ctx) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.rad, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fill();
    }
};


var line = new Line(50, 50, 200, 200, 'red'); // x1, y1, x2, y2, color
var circle = new Circle(120, 120, 50, 'green'); // x, y, r, color
var rect = new Rect(260, 130, 60, 120, 'blue'); // x, y, w, h, color


function Canvas() {
    let canvasField = document.getElementById('c1');
    this.ctx = canvasField.getContext('2d');
    this.add = function(...args) {
        for (let i = 0; i< args.length; i++) {
            let ctx = this.ctx;
            args[i].draw(this.ctx);
        }
    }
}

let drawArea = new Canvas();
drawArea.add(line, circle, rect);
```

This is what I get.... I want it to be colored! What do I do wrong?

i am adding colors as arguments of functions, but it does not function

i tried all the ways to make the shapes colored, but i did not succeed in it, please tell me what I ought to do.

[this is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSJRA.png)

Comment: **Weird typo** Not sure how it got there, but the word `сolor` in `Figure() { this.сolor` is not `color`. Its first character is the CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER ES (U+0441), which **looks** like the letter "c", but which it isn't. So when you try to access the `.color` property later on using the correct LATIN SMALL LETTER C (U+0063) `c` letter, the js engine doesn't find it, because it's not the same property at all. So to fix this, simply rewrite that property correctly using a `c` letter.

Comment: Now, there is very little chance that anyone facing the same kind of issue will ever find your question (even if it's almost certain someone will face such a similar issue). So I did vote to close as a typo. You may want to delete it directly so that it doesn't take two more users to help close it.

Comment: And finally, if you do define the method inside the constructor, you don't need to attach the constructor's params as properties of the object for them to be accessible to said method. In `draw` you could directly do `ctx.fillStyle = color`.